# Logo looking fuzzy on smaller sizes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

I created my logo in Adobe Illustrator and i'm happy espect that when i need it smaller, it looks pretty ugly and fuzzy. Like pixels are getting squeezed.

Here is a screenshot of the original on the right and the smaller one on the left:

[image]

I am sure i am doing something wring in Illustrator since i don't have much experi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'fuzz' is called anti-aliasing. It's a raster image method to smooth lines that fall in between pixel boundaries.

But since this is Illustrator, it's likely not raster, but vector, and what you are seeing is simply Illustrator's on screen rendering. If you zoom in, the anti-aliasing will likely disappear.

The issue may return, however, if you try exporting your file as a raster image of some sorts. Given the simplicity of the logo form, however, I'd suggest just sizing it the way you want, export it, then open it in PhotoShop to tweak the pixels as you see fit.

Comment: Yes when i zoom in they disappear but when i save them for web as JPG or PNG it is fuzzy again. So the solution is to export it and then modify it in photoshop? Is this the common way to do it?

Comment: That's one way to do it. I think you can set up a pixel grid in illustrator so that every line will end up on the edge of a rasterized pixel. But I don't usually trust AI's exporting much, so typically do all the raster conversion in a raster app like PhotoShop.

Comment: @drale2k I personally find it somewhat unnarural to save anything to raster from illustrator, so what I quite of then do, is either I have something like pdf saved from illustrator (vector) which I open in photoshop if I need raster version of it, or I just copy from illustrator and then paste in photoshop and most likely choose to keep it as Smart object, there is no need to export it in between, if there is no need for extra file laying around.

Comment: So you would "Save it for web" in illustrator and save it as PNG or JPG, then go into PS and cut pixles or half-tone pixels or what do you mean by "do all the raster conversion in a raster app like PhotoShop".

Thank you very much

Comment: @Joonas Yeah i used to try it that way but it still looks not good for me when scaled down. Is it because of the nature of the shape? Maybe having rectangles next to each other does not scale well, or should it work?

Comment: @drale2k Well.. I wasn't being very specific, I just wanted the world to hear I prefer photoshop over illustration for raster work :D This is what I would do: **1.** Copy & Paste to photoshop. **2.** Choose to paste as pixels (or lets say I want/need to upsize it, I would paste it in as Smartobject, make it possibly bigger and then rasterize, raterizing is important). **3.** Then I would go to Image resize `Ctrl+Alt+I` and very importantly, choose: **Nearest neighbor** from the dropdown list at the bottom of the window, then downsize the image. - This should leave you with very clear edges.

Comment: Here's an example where I resized your bigger example image with the method in my prior comment http://i.stack.imgur.com/SjPBt.jpg - Also, in some cases ( not in this case ) with small images, one tip could be to use the Sharpen filter ( even few times ) after you have downsized it. ( Though it doesn't do miracles :) ).

Comment: it comes down to if you want sharp edges on low-resolution, geometric based images, you gotta get in there at the pixel level and tweak.

Answer (score 3):

I found simple and incredible tip for rasterizing with high quality in Illustrator.

I press <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Export...</kbd> -> next you choose name and press <kbd>Epxress</kbd> another time and in the next window you click choose "type optimised" and <kbd>ok</kbd>. I never got such a high quality export results until this "solution" -

[image]

Comment: This comment is a lifesaver. You'd think that Illustrator, if you're designing an image to specific pixel specs and want to Save for Web, would have an option to rasterize at 300ppi but export at 72ppi. But instead it tries to go straight to 72ppi, which causes really blocky images. So it's much better to do exactly what this answer says, then resize the resulting larger images in Photoshop or Preview to 24% of their original size (72/300).

Answer (score 1):

The best way is probably to go through Photoshop (like suggested by DA01) with your file. If you are unsure how much to tweak, here is an excellent tutorial on downsizing logos for smaller use: http://methodandcraft.com/videos/pixel-hinting-vectors-in-photoshop

Comment: That helps a lot! Unfortunately i can't vote up answers yet.

Comment: haha, ok. but thanks for the feedback that it helped.